# Nokogiri XPath not finding certain nodes

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to modify an existing XML but I am having trouble selecting certain nodes.

Here is the relevant snippet of XML:

```
<ProductCatalog>
  <ProductLineItem>
    <updi:ProductIdentification>
      <updi:ProductName>800-22283-03</updi:ProductName>
```

I can locate the lower two nodes with:

```
doc.xpath("//updi:ProductIdentification") => #<Nokogiri::XML...
doc.xpath("//updi:ProductName") => #<Nokogiri::XML...
```

However if I try to select one of the upper nodes:

```
doc.xpath("//ProductLineItem") => []
```

I get back an empty array. It seems to have something to do with the prefixes. I can locate any element that has a prefix, but can't find elements with no prefix.

UPDATE: Here is the (quite lengthy) namespace:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ProductCatalogInformationDistribution:xsd:schema:01.00 ..\..\XML\Interchange\ProductCatalogInformationDistribution_01_00.xsd"
xmlns:dplcs="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Design:ProductLifeCycleStatusCode:xsd:codelist:01.03"
xmlns:rrt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:RateType:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:dl="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:xsd:schema:02.15" 
xmlns:ictc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Design:CatalogType:xsd:codelist:01.00" 
xmlns:updi="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ProductIdentification:xsd:schema:01.04" 
xmlns:dddt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Design:DateType:xsd:codelist:01.00" 
xmlns:dsdc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:ShipDateCode:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:ucr="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Currency:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:dpiac="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:PortIdentifierAuthorityCode:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:rptc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:PricingTypeCode:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dit="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:InventoryType:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dtt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:TransactionType:xsd:codelist:01.04" 
xmlns:upd="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:PhysicalDimension:xsd:schema:01.05" 
xmlns:dcst="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:CustomsType:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dsd="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:ShippingDocument:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:uci="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ContactInformation:xsd:schema:01.03" 
xmlns:dpcm="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:PurchaseMethod:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:rpsc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:ProductStatusCode:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:dgrc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Marketing:GeographicRegionCode:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:dtrt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:TrackingReferenceType:xsd:codelist:01.06" 
xmlns:umtq="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:MimeTypeQualifier:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:dcrt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:CustomerType:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dscd="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:ShipmentChangeDisposition:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:uc="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Country:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ProductCatalogInformationDistribution:xsd:schema:01.00" 
xmlns:dpc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:PaymentCondition:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:rpmt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:PaymentType:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:dft="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:FinanceTerms:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dtq="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:TotalQualifier:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:ume="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:MonetaryExpression:xsd:schema:01.04" 
xmlns:dcp="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Design:Compliant:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:drsc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Marketing:RegistrationStatusCode:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:uat="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:AbstractType:xsd:schema:01.02" 
xmlns:dp="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:xsd:schema:02.17" 
xmlns:rpm="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:PaymentMethod:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:dfrt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:ForecastReferenceType:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dtec="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:TaxExemptionCode:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:ulc="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Locations:xsd:schema:01.04" 
xmlns:dccc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:CreditCardClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:drlc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:ReturnLabelCode:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:st="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" 
xmlns:dnecc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:NationalExportControlClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:rpktc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:PackageTypeCode:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:uwt="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:WeightType:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:dfpt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:FreightPaymentTerms:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dte="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:TransportEvent:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:ul="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Language:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:dbpq="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:BookPriceQualifier:xsd:codelist:01.04" 
xmlns:drl="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:RouteLocation:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:ssdh="urn:rosettanet:specification:system:StandardDocumentHeader:xsd:schema:01.16" 
xmlns:dmk="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Marketing:xsd:schema:02.12" 
xmlns:rmat="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:MonetaryAmountType:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:uuom="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:UnitOfMeasure:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dfe="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:ForecastEvent:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dst="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:ShipmentTerms:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:udt="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:DataType:xsd:schema:01.04" 
xmlns:dacc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:AccountClassification:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dptt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:PortType:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:sha="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:xsd:schema:01.10" 
xmlns:dlv="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Design:Level:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:rict="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:InvoiceChargeType:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:utt="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:TaxType:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:ddwsr="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Marketing:DesignWinStatusReason:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dsm="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:ShipmentMode:xsd:codelist:01.05" 
xmlns:udct="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:DocumentType:xsd:codelist:01.09" 
xmlns:dac="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Design:ActionCode:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:dpsr="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:ProductSubstitutionReason:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:sft="urn:rosettanet:specification:system:TPIRFileType:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:dltcc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:LeadTimeClassificationCode:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:ri="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:Interval:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:urss="urn:rosettanet:specification:system:xml:1.0" 
xmlns:dds="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Design:xsd:schema:02.15" 
xmlns:dslt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:SaleType:xsd:codelist:01.04" 
xmlns:udc="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Document:xsd:schema:01.08" 
xmlns:dabcc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Design:ABCCode:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:dppt="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:ProductProcurementType:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:rwtc="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:WarrantyType:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:dlit="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:InstructionType:xsd:codelist:01.00" 
xmlns:rfob="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:FreeOnBoard:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:upri="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:ProcessRoleIdentifier:xsd:codelist:01.08" 
xmlns:ddrn="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Marketing:DesignRegistrationNotification:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:dsh="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:SpecialHandling:xsd:codelist:01.04" 
xmlns:ud="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Dates:xsd:schema:01.03" 
xmlns:dpms="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Marketing:ProjectMarketSegment:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:rssl="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:ShippingServiceLevel:xsd:codelist:01.01" 
xmlns:dldr="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:LotDiscrepancyReason:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:rat="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Shared:AmountType:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:upi="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:PartnerIdentification:xsd:schema:01.12" 
xmlns:ddp="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Marketing:Disposition:xsd:codelist:01.02" 
xmlns:dsfr="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:SpecialFulfillmentRequest:xsd:codelist:01.03" 
xmlns:ucs="urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:CountrySubdivision:xsd:codelist:01.02
```

Comment: What is the namespace on the root of your document?

Comment: It is quite long.... i will add it to my question

Comment: See my answer below; your update is not the namespace of the document. You're looking for an `xmlns="…"` attribute on your root element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest quick-hack solution is to remove namespaces from your document altogether:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = Nokogiri.XML "<root xmlns='foo' xmlns:bar='whee'><a/><bar:b /></root>"

p xml.xpath('//b').length     #=> 0
p xml.xpath('//bar:b').length #=> 1
p xml.xpath('//a').length     #=> 0
xml.remove_namespaces!
p xml.xpath('//a').length     #=> 1
p xml.xpath('//b').length     #=> 1
```

However, the above is not a valid solution if you need to preserve namespaces (e.g. modifying your document and resaving it, or you have conflicting element or attribute names amongst the various namespaces). If you can't nuke the namespaces, you can either create a prefix and tell Nokogiri what it corresponds to…

```
xml = Nokogiri.XML "<root xmlns='foo' xmlns:bar='whee'><a/><bar:b /></root>"
p xml.xpath('//x:a','x'=>'foo').length  #=> 1
```

…where the string `foo` is the URI for the namespace of the owning element in your document that has a default namespace (usually on the root), and the string `x` is whatever you want it to be (that doesn't conflict with another namespace already declared in your document). Or, more simply, you can just use `xmlns` as a prefix for the default namespace:

```
p xml.xpath('//xmlns:a').length  #=> 1
```

Alternatively, if you need to leave the namespaces and can construct a reasonable CSS-style selector to get the nodes you need then you can use the `css` method:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = Nokogiri.XML "<root xmlns='foo' xmlns:bar='whee'>
  <a/>
  <bar:b />
  <c xmlns='jim'><d/></c>
</root>"

p xml.css('a').length, #=> 1
  xml.css('b').length, #=> 0
  xml.css('c').length, #=> 0
  xml.css('d').length  #=> 0
```

As shown above, note that this only works for nodes that are in the same namespace as the root element.

Comment: My understanding of namespaces is quite rudimentary. I don't really understand why that works.... but it does!!! thanks.

Comment: @Pynner Each XML element and attribute may be associated with a namespace. A namespace is just a URI used to uniquely identify it. However, it would be impossibly cumbersome to write `<http://www.w3.org/1999/svg:circle>` each time you want an SVG circle element, so there are two simpler ways to assign a namespace. 1) You can reference a namespace by a shorthand identifier prefix that you make up; e.g. `<r … xmlns:x="http://phrogz.net/foo/bar"> … <x:jim/>` creates a `jim` element in that namespace. 2) A default namespace (`xmlns`) for an element is inherited by all non-prefixed descendants.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, also for anyone else working on the same type of problem. You can refer to the default namespace by using `doc.xpath('//x:element', 'x' => doc.namespaces['xmlns'])`

Comment: @Pynner That jogged a memory. I've edited my answer above, but note that you can just use `xmlns` for the default namespace, i.e. `doc.xpath('//xmlns::element')`. I overcomplicated it originally.